# Error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, unauthorized

My application was working yesterday without any problems and today I can not run it, because I'm getting this error: Error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. How can I fix this problem?

My code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        service = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail.com", @"password")
        };

        // This is the office365 webservice URL
        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        List<string> contactNames = accountNamez.Select(s => (string)s).ToList();

        var contactNames2 = contactNames.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

        int offset = 0;
        int pageSize = 50;

        ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);

        view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;

        PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
        {
            RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
        };

        ExtendedPropertyDefinition allFoldersType =
            new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(13825, MapiPropertyType.Integer);

        FolderId rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
        FolderView folderView = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);
        folderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;

        SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(allFoldersType, "2");
        SearchFilter searchFilter2 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "allitems");

        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection =
            new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
        searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter1);
        searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter2);

// I'm getting error here
            findFoldersResults = service.FindFolders(rootFolderId, searchFilterCollection, folderView);

        Folder allItemsFolder = findFoldersResults.Folders[0];
}
```

I also tried to make test connectivity here: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

My test:
[image]

I found one article from the first of September: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437 Is this article somehow connected with my problem?

Comment: We have just migrated an application from EWS to Microsoft Graph in my office because EWS is being shut down. It's being done bit by bit and we saw some errors at times too. I can't say for sure what your issue is but, if you haven't already, you should plan to migrate to Microsoft Graph ASAP as EWS will stop working altogether soon.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your reply. Do you have good links on how to migrate the system to Microsoft Graph?

Comment: It wasn't me who did the bulk of the work I'm afraid, so no.

Comment: You need to upgrade from Basic Authentication to OAuth. [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)